# Using unwrap_or_else for error handling in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a rust program that has a function
‘is_input_sanitized’ that takes an input
String m, and checks if the input is free of special characters.The method is being used on a separate function in the following way.

```
let a = match is_input_sanitized(m) {
  Ok(m) => m,
  Err(_) => { return Err("error"); },
};
```

I am trying to convert this snippet into using ‘unwrap_or_else’ which will return an error when the input is not sanitized.I have read the documentation and have not been able to decipher a proper way to achieve this. Is this conversion possible?

Answer (score 9):

`unwrap_or_else` is for extracting `Result` values. It sounds to me like you don't want to *extract* the result, so much as make a new one and propagate errors. You have two different things you want to do here. The first is that you want to change the error from whatever it started as (indicating by your `_` in the pattern match) to something you control, and the second is that you want to `return` errors.

Replacing the error can be done with [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err), which takes a function (such as a closure) and applies that function to the error if the `Result` is an `Err`. If the result is `Ok`, then it returns the current `Result` unmodified.

The second problem, returning on `Err`, is exactly what the [question mark operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/result/question_mark.html) was invented for.

> Chaining results using match can get pretty untidy; luckily, the `?` operator can be used to make things pretty again. `?` is used at the end of an expression returning a `Result`, and is equivalent to a match expression, where the `Err(err)` branch expands to an early `return Err(From::from(err))`, and the `Ok(ok)` branch expands to an `ok` expression.

So what you're looking for is

```
let a = is_input_sanitized(m).map_err(|_| "error")?;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.What if I try to modify the Result as well in addition to changing the error . Will I have to move back to match statements in that case?

Comment: Modifying the `Ok` side of a result can be done with [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map). Alternatively (and probably more readable), you can do the error handling with `?` and then modify the "happy path" once you've extracted it into `a`.