# Simple error handling for precondition/argument checking in Rust

Tags: rust, error-handling

Is there a way to write error handling as simply as you can with `expect`? I often want to validate program inputs and abort the program with an error message if the input is invalid.

Example with `expect`:

```
let url = Url::parse("sdfsf")
    .expect("Error parsing URL");
// Output:
// thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:41:35:
// Error parsing URL: RelativeUrlWithoutBase
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78217365/79125) I gather that I shouldn't use `expect` for actual user errors, so how can I replicate this simplicity with user-facing [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html)?

The best I've come up with is `unwrap_or_else`:

```
let url = Url::parse("sdfsf")
    .unwrap_or_else(|e| {
      eprintln!("Error parsing URL: {}", e);
      std::process::exit(1);
    });
// Output:
// Error parsing URL: relative URL without a base
```

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281235/how-to-cleanly-end-the-program-with-an-exit-code) that exit doesn't call destructors, so maybe that will cause me problems later.

---

For more context, here's a complete program that parses arguments with clap and I validate them. Currently it panics on failure, but it should display nice error messages:

```
use clap::Parser;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::process::Command;
use url::Url;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Args {
    /// Url with log information to view.
    #[arg(short, long)]
    url: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    let url = Url::parse(args.url.as_str()).expect("Error parsing URL");

    let query: HashMap<String, String> = url.query_pairs().into_owned().collect();

    let server_url = query
        .get("server_url")
        .expect("No server_url specified in url.");

    let revision = query
        .get("revision")
        .expect("No revision specified in url.");

    Command::new("TortoiseProc.exe")
        .arg("/command:log")
        .arg(format!("/startrev:{revision}"))
        .arg(format!("/path:{server_url}"))
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command.");
}
```

<sub>Related but unhelpful questions: [Using unwrap_or_else for error handling in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023600/using-unwrap-or-else-for-error-handling-in-rust), [More compact, easier to read Rust error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071158/more-compact-easier-to-read-rust-error-handling) (neither actually answer their titular question). [How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505639/how-to-do-error-handling-in-rust-and-what-are-the-common-pitfalls) doesn't address the "print error" part of my error handling.</sub>

Comment: Please read a chapter on [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) from The Rust Book.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do error propagation in Rust is using the `?` operator. The `anyhow` library makes this really convenient by providing a type that wraps `Box<dyn Error>`, thus allowing propagating different errors into a simple one that just contains the error message. It also has a `context()` method that adds context to the error. Since `main()` can return a `Result`, example of usage could look like this:

```
use url::Url;
use anyhow::Context;

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let url = Url::parse("sdsdf").context("Error parsing URL")?;
    println!("{}", url.scheme());
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `let foo = match bar {}` statement to do this.

```rust
let url = match Url::parse("sdfsf") {
  Ok(url) => url,
  Err(error) => panic!{"Error parsing URL: {:?}", error}
}
```

This way also allows you to execute extra code in the event of an Ok(()) or Err(()), such as follows:

```rust
let url = match Url::parse("sdfsf") {
  Ok(url) => {
    println!("URL parsed successfully!");
    url
  },
  Err(error) => panic!{"Error parsing URL: {:?}", error}
}
```

Comment: This code could be improved by `let`-`else`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman My apologies, how could it be improved? Could you post some docs for me to read up on it? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: My mistake, you're printing the error, so it cannot.

Comment: But this code panics and seems verbose. I want to gracefully handle and report errors. I've updated my question with a complete program.

Answer (score -4):

Reading deeper into [Chayim Friedman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78217365/79125), I realized I can write my own unwrap that dies on failures:

```
use url::Url;

pub trait UnwrapExt<T> {
    fn unwrap_or_error(self, msg: &str) -> T;
}

impl<T, E: std::fmt::Display> UnwrapExt<T> for Result<T, E> {
    fn unwrap_or_error(self, msg: &str) -> T {
        self.unwrap_or_else(|err| {
            eprintln!("{msg}: {}", { err });
            std::process::exit(1);
        })
    }
}

impl<T> UnwrapExt<T> for Option<T> {
    fn unwrap_or_error(self, msg: &str) -> T {
        self.unwrap_or_else(|| {
            eprintln!("{msg}");
            std::process::exit(1);
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let url = Url::parse("sdsdf")
        .unwrap_or_error("Error parsing URL");

    println!("{}", url.scheme());
}
// Output:
// Error parsing URL: relative URL without a base
```

That works nicely for this case!

Comment: This works for your case, but it's not idiomatic or composable, as it doesn't allow errors to be _handled_ up the stack. Normally errors are propagated upward and eventually displayed near or at top-level. Here is much shorter code that achieves the same purpose: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe5fc03c2b14ed70f6edae5487ea7915

Comment: How could errors be handled up the stack when I'm validating inputs to the program in main? It can't go higher, right? My entire purpose is to handle errors and abort. I've updated my question with a complete program. However `anyhow::Context` does look nice -- seems like it includes an error message without losing the result object.

Comment: In this case no explicit handling is necessary, as `?` gets you out of `main()`, whose caller exits and prints the error before doing so, which is what you want (and what my snippet demonstrates). The code in the answer always exits the process, so it can't be easily factored out of `main()` and reused for another purpose, such as in a library. Of course, it works, and you can certainly use it if it suits you, it's just not a good example for future StackOverflow visitors to emulate, hence the downvotes.

Comment: @user4815162342: Could you add that as an answer? It seems like a good solution and you have a great explanation for why it's a good approach.

Comment: I've now added an answer. I didn't do so originally because I felt that this was sufficiently covered by existing answers. But now I see that a clear demonstration of `anyhow` does add value for your particular use case. Thanks for gracefully accepting the criticism, and have fun with learning Rust!